# Give head to an already headless Selenium Firefox/Chrome session

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, firefox, webdriver

I am writing a test bot for an app. Generally I need it to be in headless mode. But at some arbitrary buggy occasions it is a comfort to see the browser window and decide if what a wrong issue is happening there. So I need a way to connect a browser window to an active headless session. In an other word to literally convert it to a head-full one.

P.S. Every thing is in Python. Both Firefox and Chrome solutions(or any sort of guiding) are welcomed.

Comment: What did you try until now?

Comment: Did you do some research and test to see if you are able to achieve the result by yourself?

Comment: @soundwave Being here is a part of my parallelized-research strategy. I've edited my question to cover this issue. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: hi @S.Khajeh i have also deleted my comment. thanks -- i hope somebody can help with your question!  if i can think of something i'll post back.

Comment: Maybe it is possible to loop over all the `WebElement` objects present in the `WebDriver` scope to recreate the Web Page and then project it into a local port.

Comment: But it doesn't guaranty IO sync between the resulting webpage and the actual headless one, which is what I actually am seeking right now.